# Generating random variables with specific correlation threshold value

Tags: r, correlation

I am generating random variables with specified range and dimension.I have made a following code for this.

```
generateRandom <- function(size,scale){
  result<- round(runif(size,1,scale),1)
  return(result)
}

flag=TRUE
x <- generateRandom(300,6)
y <- generateRandom(300,6)
while(flag){
  corrXY <- cor(x,y)
  if(corrXY>=0.2){
    flag=FALSE
  }
  else{
    x <- generateRandom(300,6)
    y <- generateRandom(300,6)
  }

}
```

I want following **6 variables** with **size 300** and **scale** of all is between **1 to** **6** except for **one variable which would have scale 1-7** with following correlation structure among them.

```
1 0.45  -0.35  0.46  0.25 0.3
     1   0.25  0.29  0.5  -0.3
         1    -0.3   0.1   0.4
               1     0.4   0.6
                      1    -0.4
                             1
```

But when I try to increase threshold value my program gets very slow.Moreover,I want more than 7 variables of size 300 and between each pair of those variables I want some specific correlation threshold.How would I do it efficiently?

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/generate-pairs-of-random-numbers-uniformly-distributed-and-correlated)?

Comment: I tried it on a 3 variable example with correlation > 0.8, and even the rounding does not affect much the target correlation. Plus it's very fast!

Comment: @VincentGuillemot I have specific requirement of range of values in a given random variable for example here I want values in the range 1 to 6 and 1 to 5 for other.Moreover,I have few variables and between each variable requirement of correlation threshold value vary.

Comment: Once you have a uniform variable with values between 0 and 1, you can transform it to have a variable between 1 and 6 by multiplying it by 5 and adding 1. It won't change its correlation with another variable.

Comment: and what generating 5 or more variables with different correlation threshold values among them?

Comment: Could you specify in your question the number of variables you want, the range of values and the correlation structure?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108813/discussion-between-vincent-guillemot-and-naseer-ahmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is directly inspired from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/generate-pairs-of-random-numbers-uniformly-distributed-and-correlated) and [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37424/how-to-simulate-from-a-gaussian-copula/64988#64988).

We would like to generate 300 samples of a 6-variate uniform distribution with correlation structure equal to

```
Rhos <- matrix(0, 6, 6)
Rhos[lower.tri(Rhos)] <- c(0.450, -0.35, 0.46, 0.25, 0.3,
                           0.25, 0.29, 0.5, -0.3, -0.3,
                           0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, -0.4)
Rhos <- Rhos + t(Rhos)
diag(Rhos) <- 1
```

We first generate from this correlation structure the correlation structure of the Gaussian copula:

```
Copucov <- 2 * sin(Rhos * pi/6)
```

This matrix is not positive definite, we use instead the nearest positive definite matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
Copucov <- cov2cor(nearPD(Copucov)$mat)
```

This correlation structure can be used as one of the inputs of `MASS::mvrnorm`:

```
G <- mvrnorm(n=300, mu=rep(0,6), Sigma=Copucov, empirical=TRUE)
```

We then transform `G` into a multivariate uniform sample whose values range from 1 to 6, except for the last variable which ranges from 1 to 7:

```
U <- matrix(NA, 300, 6)
U[, 1:5] <- 5 * pnorm(G[, 1:5]) + 1
U[, 6] <- 6 * pnorm(G[, 6]) + 1
```

After rounding (and taking the nearest positive matrix to the copula's covariance matrix etc.), the correlation structure is not changed much:

```
Ur <- round(U, 1)
cor(Ur)
```

Comment: I edited my answer to account for a more complex correlation structure.

Comment: I m not getting the desired results?

Comment: You will have to be more specific

Comment: Just a side note: the correlations cannot be *exactly* the correlations you specified. And in the example you, they will even be pretty far from the correlations you gave because the specified correlation matrix is not positive definite (and therefore not a correlation matrix).